# Convert Multiple PowerPoint Files to PDF using CMD

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Any way to convert multiple PowerPoint files in a folder to PDF using Windows command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not fail safe (you can add file existence checks and so on). Save this as a `.bat`:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%
    
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var source=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var target=WScript.Arguments.Item(1);
PP = new ActiveXObject("PowerPoint.Application");
PRSNT = PP.presentations.Open(source,0,0,0)
//PRSNT.SaveCopyAs(target,32);
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/ppsaveasfiletype-enumeration-powerpoint
PRSNT.SaveAs(target,32);
PRSNT.Close();
PP.Quit();
```

The first argument is the powerpoint file the second is the new file where you want to save it. More info about the [presentation object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/presentation-object-powerpoint)

Next step is to process files(if the previous script is saved as `ppt2pdf.bat`):

```
@echo off
::change the locataion in the line bellow
set "ppt_dir=c:\ppts"
for %%a in ("%ppt_dir%\*pptx" "%ppt_dir%\*ppt") do (
  call ppt2pdf.bat "%%~fa" "%%~dpna.pdf"
)
```

Comment: nice solution! is it possibble to set the output path?

Comment: @Andrea_86 - you can. Use `set "output_dir=c:\output"` somewhere in the beginning of the second script and then use `call ppt2pdf.bat "%%~fa" "%output_dir%\%%~nxa.pdf"`

Comment: Awesome, works like charm.